# Azure Function app and root certification

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-functions, tls1.2

I have an Azure Function App. When I call it using a web browser it shows that a root certification is required, as it used the Baltimore cert.

But when i use an simple device(GSM module) or POSTMAN, i can call my API without this root certificate. Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the certificate got already [added one in your postman](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/api-management-validate-api-requests-through-client-certificate/ba-p/1500941). To check it, you can navigate to your **Postman >> Settings >> Certificates**.

[image]

or you might have already [setup the postman](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-access-azure-key-vault-secrets-through-rest-api-using-postman/) which calls key vault's Client Id and Certificate

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Calling an Azure AD secured API with Postman](https://dev.to/425show/calling-an-azure-ad-secured-api-with-postman-22co)